# How to align an element in a flexible row in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a chat bubble with username, timestamp and chat message. It is divided into two rows.

First row is username and timestamp, second row is the chat message.

With the code below it looks like this:

[image]

I want the timestamp to be aligned right but the blue box should not be wider then the message line except the message is shorter than username and timestamp.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Username"),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Text("5 mins ago"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                          maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 120),
                      child: Text("A long message text 123456789")),
                ],
              ))
        ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Username"),
                  Spacer(),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text("5 mins ago"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: With Spacer this error is thrown: `RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#63fab relayoutBoundary=up24 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'`

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Username"),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text("5 mins ago"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text("A long message text 123456789"),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.`

Comment: Hi, @MarcS82 i have updated my answer, that will solve your issue

Comment: Thank you for your help. In your solution the chat box has a fixed with. What I need is the look of the chat bubbles in Whatsapp. The width depends on the length of the text but the minumum width is the with of username + date.